Authorization issue while deploying code via CI CD into the Azure functions
We have provisioned a Azure function in Private Endpoint and Gitlab runner in Gitlab CI CD.
While we are trying to deploy the code we are getting the following error:

Code: Authorization
Message: The Client 'client ID of service principal' with a object ID 'object id' does not have authorization to perform the action 'Microsoft.web/sites/functions/read' over scope /subscriptions/'subscription ID'/resourceGroups/'resourcegroupname'/Microsoft.web/sites/'functionappname'/functions/'nameoffunction'
or scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh the credentials.

The Service principal is access on the resource group level with the customized admin with Microsoft.web/, Microsoft.web/sites/ and Microsoft.web/sites/functions/*


Is there any other place that i missed the granting the access?
Checked the IAM roles of the service principal and observed that there is a customized IAM role given foe the service principal on the resource groups. Is there any specific API permission to be granted to the service principal?

Did you grant necessary permissions to deploy the function?

The Client 'client ID of service principal' with a object ID 'object id' does not have authorization to perform the action 'Microsoft.web/sites/functions/read' over scope /subscriptions/'subscription ID'/resourceGroups/'resourcegroupname'/Microsoft.web/sites/'functionappname'/functions/'nameoffunction' or scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh the credentials.

To resolve this error, assign Reader role (allows the Microsoft.web/sites/functions/read action) to the Service Principal in the Azure function app.

Go to Function App=>Access Role(IAM)=>Add Role Assignment=>Select Reader role, Assign the role to the Service Principal.



Create a function app with private endpoints enabled and configure virtual network with subnets, refer MSDOC and my SO answer.



To deploy a function to Azure function App which is configured with Private endpoints, add below application settings under Function app=>settings=>Environment Variables=>App Settings.

WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER=168.63.129.16
WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1
WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET=1

Portal:
Deployed the function to Azure:

